# How to integrate elm-format with Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, elm, package-control

I'm trying to make `elm-format` work in Sublime Text and am following these instructions: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Elm%20Language%20Support

Step one says:
**"Make sure `elm-format` is in your PATH"**

What does that mean? How do I find my path?

Comment: What platform are you on? (Win, OS X, Linux)

Comment: @pdamoc I'm on Mac OS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PATH` is the environment variable holding the list of directories that will be searched when you try to execute a command (like entering `elm-format` on the command line).

In the terminal, you can enter `echo $PATH` to get a colon separated list of all the directories in your `PATH`.

What it means is that you'll need to get the `elm-format` binary (there are instructions [here](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format#installation-)) and place it in one of those directories (`/usr/local/bin` is a common choice).

Comment: I had the same issue, should I move all the elm-format directory to /usr/local/bin or what file should I move

Comment: As a follow-up, I needed to set my path to `/usr/local/bin/` (with the trailing slash) to get it to work.